# Unable to call the validateUsername function inside btnRegAcc.setOnClickListener button

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class RegisterActivity  : AppCompatActivity (){
    lateinit var regUsername : EditText
    lateinit var regEmail : EditText
    lateinit var regPassword : EditText
    lateinit var cfmPassword : EditText
    lateinit var  regPhone : EditText
    lateinit var btnRegAcc : Button
    lateinit var btnBack : Button
    lateinit var connection : Connection

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

        regUsername = findViewById(R.id.regUsername)
        regEmail = findViewById(R.id.regEmail)
        regPassword = findViewById(R.id.regPassword)
        cfmPassword = findViewById(R.id.cfmPassword)
        regPhone = findViewById(R.id.regPhone)
        btnRegAcc = findViewById(R.id.btnRegAcc)
        btnBack = findViewById(R.id.btnBack)

        Toast.makeText(this,"Register Page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        btnRegAcc.setOnClickListener{

            validateUserName()
            var email : String = regEmail.text.toString()
            var pass : String = regPassword.text.toString()
            var cfm : String = cfmPassword.text.toString()
            var phone : String = regPhone.text.toString()

            if (regUsername.text.trim().isNotEmpty() && regPassword.text.trim().isNotEmpty() && regEmail.text.trim().isNotEmpty()
                && cfmPassword.text.trim().isNotEmpty() && regPhone.text.trim().isNotEmpty() ) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Checking Authentication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill all information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        fun validateUserName() : Boolean{
            var Username: String = regUsername.text.toString().trim()
            if (Username.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Username is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return false
            }
            else if (Username.length <= 8){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ensures that the Username has at least 8 characters", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return false
            }
            else {
                return true
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove validateUserName() funtion out of onCreate() block .

```
class RegisterActivity  : AppCompatActivity () {
lateinit var regUsername: EditText
lateinit var regEmail: EditText
lateinit var regPassword: EditText
lateinit var cfmPassword: EditText
lateinit var regPhone: EditText
lateinit var btnRegAcc: Button
lateinit var btnBack: Button
lateinit var connection: Connection

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

    regUsername = findViewById(R.id.regUsername)
    regEmail = findViewById(R.id.regEmail)
    regPassword = findViewById(R.id.regPassword)
    cfmPassword = findViewById(R.id.cfmPassword)
    regPhone = findViewById(R.id.regPhone)
    btnRegAcc = findViewById(R.id.btnRegAcc)
    btnBack = findViewById(R.id.btnBack)

    Toast.makeText(this, "Register Page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    btnRegAcc.setOnClickListener {

        validateUserName()
        var email: String = regEmail.text.toString()
        var pass: String = regPassword.text.toString()
        var cfm: String = cfmPassword.text.toString()
        var phone: String = regPhone.text.toString()

        if (regUsername.text.trim().isNotEmpty() && regPassword.text.trim()
                .isNotEmpty() && regEmail.text.trim().isNotEmpty()
            && cfmPassword.text.trim().isNotEmpty() && regPhone.text.trim().isNotEmpty()
        ) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Checking Authentication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill all information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

fun validateUserName(): Boolean {
    var Username: String = regUsername.text.toString().trim()
    if (Username.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Username is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        return false
    } else if (Username.length <= 8) {
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Ensures that the Username has at least 8 characters",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

}

Comment: But how do I call the validateUserName() if i removed it ? I am trying to call the function inside the button.